# Android Push with Tags using Urban Airship

Tags: android, tags, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I integrated urban airship push notification in my application and it's working fine. But, my problem is, when I working with
tags I'm not receiving proper tag message correctly.

**Explanation:**

In my application I have two options:

```
                     1.Male
                     2.Female
```

If I logged as `Male` I used  below line of code to set tag for `PushManager`:

```
Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
tags.add("Male");
PushManager.shared().setTags(tags);
```

For `Female` I set as

```
tags = new HashSet<String>();
tags.add("Female");
PushManager.shared().setTags(tags);
```

Now, from my Urban airship account Under Development I created same tags `Male` and `Female`

If I choose tag as Male and sends a push message.

**Expected Result:**

What are all the devices logged as Male will receives the message.

**Current Result:**
All the device received the message(Male and Female)

I provide all keys and GCM Sender correctly.

**Observations:**

```
 1.In my log-cat selected tag sends correctly

 2.In Urban airship->Audience->App Id's: My current app id registered with correct Tag(currently I logged as Male)
```

**Note:** In Error Console of UrbanAirship it shown as:

```
Application does not have permission to send to this device
Original Message: Error: mismatched sender ID
```

Can any one please give me solution for this?

Where is the problem and how to achieve??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

usually means there's a discrepancy with the gcmSender property value in your airshipconfig.properties file; check the value for that key and make sure it's the numeric value for your app in the google api console